# What's difference between class QWebView; vs. #include <QWebView>

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

What's difference between these defining;

```
#include "QWebView"

class QWebView;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`class QWebView;` is a so called *forward declaration*. That means, you can't access details of the class (like methods/public variables) until the type is completely declared. The forward declaration, only tells the compiler *that* this particular type *exists*, whereas the full include tells the compiler, what methods etc. that class provides.

If you just wan't to use the type in a declaration, it's fine. But as soon, as you call a method on a variable of type `QWebView`, you will get an error, if you don't include the full declaration.